# graph structure, find parent using stored procedure, postgres

Tags: stored-procedures, graph

I am new to stored procedures. As part of our application, we have a database with one of the tables having child-parent relationships. Given an id, we should be able to figure out the final parent of the id, traversing through the child-parent links in the table.

[image: sample data]

Input1: 10943,
Output1: 8656

Input2: 5005,
Output2: 9151, 9160

**Different possibilities**

An id could have multiple final parents, 
An id may not have a parent

Any inputs would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**TREE STRUCTURE ANSWER:**

It all depends on how is the **flow** of your data, I mean, how your childs and parents behave in time (inserts, updates) and how big could be the table (hundreds,thousands).

We can summarize the cases in two: big table (thousands+ rows) and small table (hundreds- rows). In any case, you could use a **"result"** table to hold the first parent of all the children.

**SMALL TABLE**

If your table is not going to be a big one, then its ok to put all in a PL. and call the PL when you want to materialize the **"result"** table.

**BIG TABLE**

If your table is going to be big (really big), then you would have to use triggers to update the **"result"** table. And this **"result"** would have to be an [Eager Materialized View](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/materialized-view-strategies-using-postgresql#eager-materialized-view). In order for it to work fluently and not having to wait minutes for every transaction.

Here's an example on how you could do it in case of a Small Table, if it's big, it would be similar but you would have to work hard on the triggers to make it work OK. This example shows the PL in a DO format only for explanatory purposes, you could change that for a PL easily:

```
-- YOUR EXAMPLE TABLE, without child with two parents
CREATE TEMP TABLE demo (child integer,parent integer);
INSERT INTO demo VALUES
(10943,6766),
(6766,9003),
(9003,8656),
(5005,6995),
(6995,9151),
(6996,9160);

-- DO, for inline PL
DO $$
DECLARE
-- Variables, note that for variable asignation its better if you use ':='
    fathers integer[] := NULL;
    father integer := 0;
    firstfather integer := 0;
    no_father boolean := 'f';
    sons integer[] := NULL;
    son integer := 0;
    row integer := 1;
    rows_length integer := 0;
BEGIN
-- Create "result" table for the example, the drop is in case you test many times the code
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS result;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE result (sons integer,fathers integer);
    SELECT array(SELECT child FROM demo)
    INTO sons;
    rows_length := array_length(sons,1);
-- Code that gets the first father of a child
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'son: %',sons[row];
        son = sons[row];
        LOOP
            father := (SELECT parent FROM demo WHERE child=son);
            IF father IS NULL
            THEN
                no_father='f';
            ELSE
                no_father='t';
                fathers[row] := father;
                son = father;
            END IF;
            EXIT WHEN no_father='f';
        END LOOP;    
        RAISE NOTICE 'father: %',fathers[row];
-- INSERT in "result" son with its first father
        INSERT into result(sons,fathers) values(sons[row],fathers[row]);
        row := row+1;
        EXIT WHEN rows_length < row;
    END LOOP;
END $$;
-- Display "result"
SELECT * FROM result;
```

This code generate the next table:

```
Sons    Fathers
---------------
10943   8656
6766    8656
9003    8656
5005    9151
6995    9151
6996    9160
```

**NOTE:** Your table shows a child with two fathers (6995), that's not possible in a tree structure, this example works in a tree structure where every child has one parent.

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks much for investing your time. I apologize for mentioning it as a tree, it's actually a graph structure.

Comment: No problem @funnyguy. If your using a graph structure you just have to make some adjustments to the code, but you would have to define how you would handle the data. It could be all in a column separated by commas.

Comment: Mmm... @funnyguy, I've reviewed the code and for it to work in graphs its a little more complex... it's needed Window Functions for it to work.

Comment: I've tested @Лев Макаренко 's code, and it's really clever, but doesn't work when the "tree" has many leaves in different levels.

Comment: More the less @funnyguy should explain the structure of the nodes, because if they are tree like, you have to do "something", but if the nodes are redundant... well the solution is different and it should use paths algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Using Common Table Expressions (CTE) make it much easier to write this as a query instead of as a procedure.

Let say we have this table `al_test`:

```
+-----------+----------+
| parent_id | child_id |
+-----------+----------+
| 10943     | 6766     |
+-----------+----------+
| 6766      | 9003     |
+-----------+----------+
| 9003      | 8656     |
+-----------+----------+
| 5005      | 6995     |
+-----------+----------+
| 6995      | 9151     |
+-----------+----------+
| 6995      | 9160     |
+-----------+----------+
```

For example (PostgreSQL 8.4+), to get all parents for node 5005:

```
WITH RECURSIVE al_tree AS (
  SELECT parent_id, child_id, 1 as depth
  FROM al_test WHERE child_id = 5005

  UNION ALL

  SELECT al_test.parent_id, al_test.child_id, al_tree.depth + 1
  FROM al_test, al_tree
    WHERE al_test.child_id = al_tree.parent_id
)

SELECT parent_id
FROM al_tree
    WHERE depth = (SELECT MAX(depth) FROM al_tree);
```

Result:

```
+-----------+
| parent_id |
+-----------+
| 9151      |
+-----------+
| 9160      |
+-----------+
```